# Magento 2 - How to pass data from Payment Method - Authorization client to custom success page

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, payment-gateway, order-success-page

I've created a payment method which uses the authorization method to connect a client to an external site, which provides me with custom data, I would like to display this data on a custom success page.

1. How would I create a sucecss page which I can display this data on?
2. The data is captured in the AuthorizeClient inside the `placeRequest` function
3. I also have a `AuthorizationHandler` which has a `handle` function and a `AuthorizationValidator` which has a `validate` function

The above facade is listed via the `di.xml`

## Update

This is part of the payment gateway that we've implemented. we get the data in the `Gateway Client` which is then forwarded to the `Response Handler` inside of the `Handler chain`, then after this process it goes to the success page

[image]

Comment: the custom data you require is stored in db ?

Comment: @Pawan please see my update.

Comment: @Pawan so between `Response Handler` and the `success page` is where I need help with

Comment: @Pawan any ideas?